# Capturing mobile phone traffic on Wireshark

Tags: android, iphone, ios, networking, wireshark

How can I capture mobile phone traffic on Wireshark?

Comment: Windows users can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65774666/10532966

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. **For Android phones, any network**: Root your phone, then install tcpdump on it. [This app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/shark-for-root/lv.n3o.shark) is a tcpdump wrapper that will install tcpdump and enable you to start captures using a GUI. *Tip: You will need to make sure you supply the right interface name for the capture and this varies from one device to another, eg **-i eth0** or **-i tiwlan0***  - or use **-i any** to log all interfaces
2. **For Android 4.0+ phones**: [Android PCAP from Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/static/android-pcap/) uses the USB OTG interface to support packet capture without requiring root. I haven't tried this app, and there are some restrictions on the type of devices supported (see their page)
3. **For Android phones**: [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) uses the Android VPN service to intercept packets and capture them. I have used this app successfully, but it also seems to affect the performance with large traffic volumes (eg video streaming)
4. **For IOS 5+ devices, any network**: iOS 5 added a **remote virtual interface (RVI)** facility that lets you use Mac OS X packet trace programs to capture traces from an iOS device. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1176/_index.html) for more details
5. **For all phones, wi-fi only:** Set up your [Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-internet-connection-mac-network-users-mchlp1540/mac) or [PC](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot) as a wireless access point, then run wireshark on the computer.
6. **For all phones, wi-fi only:** Get [a capture device](http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/cascade/wireshark_enhancements/airpcap.php) that can sniff wi-fi. This has the advantage of giving you 802.11x headers as well, but you may miss some of the packets
7. **Capture using a VPN server**: Its fairly easy to [set-up your own VPN server](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html) using OpenVPN. You can then route your traffic through your server by setting up the mobile device as [a VPN client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn) and capture the traffic on the server end.

Comment: how do I figure out the right interface name for the capture for my device (Nexus 7)? Also in the GUI within Shark, what are the right parameters to enter? Thanx

Comment: If you are interested in setting up a rogue access point on Windows 7 and above and capture packets using Wireshark, have a look at the steps I put together at http://mohit.io/blog/windows-capture-analyze-mobile-device-network-traffic/  This will work for any device that supports WiFi (Android, iOS, Wii, XBox, etc)

Comment: Regarding option 2: that's practically a non-existent option. From their page: "You will need [...] and a RTL8187 based wireless NIC"!!!!

Comment: @rupello, could you, please, explain abit more option 7? I managed to install openvpn server on interface "tun0" and managed to connect to this server from my phone. However, I cannot capture packets from this interface using scapy with the command `sniff(iface='tun0', count=10)`?

Comment: @Yury, my OpenVPN installation (the commercial one) creates two adapters for the access server, called as0t0 and as0t1. I capture the user packets using something like "sudo tcpdump -i as0t1 -s 0 -w out.cap"

Comment: @rupello, I already configured OpenVPN and scapy for sniffing traffic. There is a config parameter in the server `push "redirect-gateway def1"`that needs to be enabled. Additionally, in scapy function `sniff` it is required to use custom filter. In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: For me, the option #3 is the easiest to do simple tasks such as check what calls a certain app does.

Comment: Most of those don’t work for packets that never leave the device or if you already use a VPN. So these are useless for solving MTU/fragmentation-related problems.

Comment: There are Android firewall apps that can capture packets without root permissions. For example, [LostNet NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lostnet.fw.free&hl=en&e=-EnableAppDetailsPageRedesign).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Any idea about what approach does Lostnet uses for its working?

Comment: What if I want to do the opposite? Use my usb-connected smartphone to capture my PC's packets?

Basically run a wireshark-like software on my Android phone

Answer (score 49):

In addition to rupello's excellent answer, a "dirty" but very effective trick:

**For all phones, any (local) network**: Set up your PC to [Man-In-The-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) your mobile device.

Use [Ettercap](http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) to do [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_poisoning) between your mobile device and your router, and all your mobile's traffic will appear in Wireshark. See [this tutorial](http://openmaniak.com/ettercap_arp.php) for set-up details

Comment: You can also use [Charles proxy](http://charlesproxy.com/) on Mac OS, for capturing HTTP traffic, it has a very nice interface and functionalities. You'll need to set up your computer's local IP has a proxy on your phone. It can sniff TLS traffic too, and do it without a warning if you install Charles' certificate on the phone.

Answer (score 44):

Another option which has not been suggested here is to run the app you want to monitor in the Android emulator from the Android SDK. You can then easily capture the traffic with wireshark on the same machine.

This was the easiest option for me.

Comment: That's interesting option. Can it handle ssl packets ?

Comment: The best and the easiest option is this one. Why messing with the phone? rooting, compiling tcpdump to be compatible with ARM CPUs, arpspoofing local network to direct traffic toward ethernet BLAH BLAH BLAH and eventually run wireshark and capture the packets??. Just install the app in an emulator and capture ethernet. easy-peasy

Comment: because there are some 3rd party libraries, which could not be changed, but detects that it running on emulator and change its behaviour. And such you need real device.

Answer (score 31):

Wireshark + OSX + iOS:

Great overview so far, but if you want specifics for Wireshark + OSX + iOS:

- install Wireshark on your computer
- connect iOS device to computer via USB cable
- connect iOS device and computer to the same WiFi network
- run this command in a OSX terminal window:  `rvictl -s x` where `x` is the UDID of your iOS device.  You can find the UDID of your iOS device via iTunes (make sure you are using the UDID and not the serial number).
- goto Wireshark `Capture->Options`, a dialog box appears, click on the line `rvi0` then press the `Start` button.

[image: Wireshark Capture Options Dialog Box]

Now you will see all network traffic on the iOS device.  It can be pretty overwhelming.  A couple of pointers:

- don't use iOS with a VPN, you don't be able to make sense of the encrypted traffic
- use simple filters to focus on interesting traffic
- `ip.addr==204.144.14.134` views traffic with a source or destination address of 204.144.14.134
- `http` views only http traffic

Here's a sample window depicting TCP traffic for for pdf download from 204.144.14.134:

[image: Wireshark TCP traffic for pdf download from 204.144.14.134]

Answer (score 11):

For Android phone I used tPacketCapture:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en

This app was a lifesaver I was debugging a problem with failure of SSL/TLS handshake on my Android app. Tried to setup ad hoc networking so I could use wireshark on my laptop. It did not work for me. This app quickly allowed me to capture network traffic, share it on my Google Drive so I could download on my laptop where I could examine it with Wireshark! Awesome and no root required!

Comment: Won’t work, if your problems only occur when using a VPN (and never end up on the hub/router either).

Answer (score 8):

[Packet Capture Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture) implements a VPN that logs all network traffic on the Android device. You don't need to setup any VPN/proxy server on your PC. Does not needs root. Supports SSL decryption which tPacketCapture does not. It also includes a good log viewer.

Comment: That VPN not working... no page is opening or data is fetched... having that VPN is like having no internet connection...

Answer (score 8):

Preconditions: adb and wireshark is installed on your computer and you have a rooted android device.

1. Download [tcpdump](https://www.androidtcpdump.com/android-tcpdump/downloads) to ~/Downloads
2. `adb push ~/Downloads/tcpdump /sdcard/`
3. `adb shell`
4. `su root`
5. `mv /sdcard/tcpdump /data/local/`
6. `cd /data/local/`
7. `chmod +x tcpdump`
8. `./tcpdump -vv -i any -s 0 -w /sdcard/dump.pcap`
9. `CTRL+C` after you've captured enough packets.
10. `exit`
11. `exit`
12. `adb pull /sdcard/dump.pcap ~/Downloads/`

Now you can open the pcap file using Wireshark.

Answer (score 5):

Install Fiddler on your PC and use it as a proxy on your Android device.

Source: http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

Comment: This is only useful for HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to making your PC a wireless access point, but can be much easier, is using reverse tethering.  If you happen to have an HTC phone they have a nice reverse-tethering option called "Internet pass-through", under the network/mobile network sharing settings.  It routes all your traffic through your PC and you can just run Wireshark there.

Answer (score 3):

Make your laptop a wifi hotspot for your phone (any) and connect it to internet. Sniff Traffic on your wifi interface using wireshark.

you will get to know a lot of anti privacy stuff!

Comment: Can you  be more specific on how to do it on at least one platform (Windows, Linux or Mac OS X) ?

Comment: @FireCruZ would be great, if you mention how to do that in mac os e.g.

Answer (score 3):

As a Wireshark alternative/companion for Android, you can try my open source app [PCAPdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emanuelef.remote_capture). On non-rooted devices, it uses the VPNService to capture the traffic with some limitations. On rooted devices, it works like a user-friendly tcpdump.

You can analyze connections and packets payload directly into the app, or export the traffic in PCAP format to analyze it on a PC with Wireshark. It has many other cool features, give it a try!

Comment: Just the greatest solution for non rooted Android devices!

Comment: Can I capture the traffic from the device connected to my Android hostpot?

Comment: This depends on the OS, but usually it's not possible without root. There is a workaround to capture only the HTTP(S) traffic, which is to install an HTTP proxy server app on the Android phone acting as an hotspot and configure the client device to use this proxy.

Answer (score 1):

**For Android**, I previously used tPacketCapture but it didn't work well for an app streaming some video. I'm now using [Shark](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark). You **need to be root** to use it though.

It uses **TCPDump** (check the [arguments you can  pass](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)) and creates a **pcap file** that can be read by Wireshark. The default arguments are usually good enough for me.

Comment: Shark is no longer available on Google Play.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to have been removed. The site http://swapper.n3o.lv also doesn't seem to hold the apks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that inspired me to develop an app that could help to capture traffic from an Android device. The app features SSH server that allows you to have traffic in Wireshark on the fly ([sshdump wireshark component](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/sshdump.html)). As the app uses an OS feature called VPNService to capture traffic, it does not require the root access.

The app is in early Beta. If you have any issues/suggestions, do not hesitate to let me know.

[Download From Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egorovandreyrm.pcapremote)

[Tutorial in which you could read additional details](https://egorovandreyrm.com/pcap-remote-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS Devices:**

⦿  Open **Terminal** and simply write:

```
rvictl -s udid
```

it'll open an interface on Wireshark with a name, In my case its rvi0.

[image]

udid is iPhone's unique device id.

[(How to find my iOS Device UDID)](https://www.itexico.com/blog/find-unique-device-identifier-udid-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and found [this tutorial](https://gaikwadchetan93.medium.com/monitoring-modifying-android-app-network-traffic-via-mitm-proxy-part-1-886f6324f705) particularly helpful for capturing network traffic on Android devices (but it should also work on iOS devices).

To summarize the tutorial:

1. The computer and mobile device should be on the same network.
2. Run `brew install mitmproxy`
3. Run `mitmproxy`, which runs mitmproxy on port 8080 (by default)
4. Find your computer's private IP address.
5. On your mobile device, configure its network to use your computer's IP address, port 8080 as its proxy.
6. On your mobile device, navigate to `mitm.io` to download and install a mitmproxy-provided certificate.
7. Depending on your version of Android, you may need to explicitly tell your app to allow user CA certificates by creating a `res/xml/network_security.xml` file (with the contents shown below) and by adding `android:networkSecurityConfig=”@xml/network_security_config"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s `application` element.

```xml
<network-security-config>
   <debug-overrides>
      <trust-anchors>
         <certificates src="system" />
         <certificates src="user" />
      </trust-anchors>
   </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```