# Monitor URLs accessed by mobile app

Tags: mobile, web, monitor, traffic, packet-sniffers

I have downloaded an Android app (which is also available for iPhone and ipad). I want to monitor which URLs it is accessing. On the desktop, you can use tools like Chrome dev tools for browser traffic and Charles Proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for other app traffic. Is there a similar way to set a proxy for the app from outside it, and then view any connection attempts, possibly with headers and responses?

I only need to do it once, to ensure the app isn't malicious, so the process doesn't have to be the most convenient method in the world. For example, it could involve setting up a proxy app on the desktop and then connecting through that, or running the Android or iOS version on a desktop-based simulator and monitoring that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing mobile phone traffic on wireshark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When searching SO, a lot is to be found on this topic. The best solution seems to be setting up a desktop to be an access point for the android device and run wireshark on it like suggested here

[Capturing mobile phone traffic on wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark)

Comment: Whoops, your search skills seem a lot better than mine, this is embarassing. Nonetheless, thanks, that answer gives me reassurance that this is possible to do easily.

Answer (score -1):

your best bet is charles proxy trial version

to set up charles proxy is like butter

1) Make sure both computer and device are on the same network

2) Download charles proxy on computer

3) On device go to wifi--> connection name--> hold on to it --> modify --> manual proxy --> give your ip address and port 8888

4) keep charles open on computer while you are doing this

5) you will get a pop up in charles regarding the connection and will start showing you the traffic being captured from the app..