# Filter logcat to get internet pings like wireshark (network layer)?

Tags: android, logcat, wireshark

I heard somewhere, but I don't remember now that you can filter Android logcat to get HTTP calls/receives to/from certain websites or IPs. It is like the Wireshark software in which it shows data in the Network Layer. Or are there any other ways to get those calls from my Android phone?

I'm currently implementing ad mediation services. Therefore, I want to check the calls from the my phone to the ad servers in order to check whether its ad mediation SDK does call other ad services.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are interested in this question, here is the solution I found:
[Capturing mobile phone traffic on wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark)