# How to check if data packets are being sent ( sending and receiving ) when we are connected to internet in android

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location

i want to is there any to know that if data is being sent and received. as i m trying to build a application that take your current location. though i m able to find if internet is connected or not, but if internet is connected and so my app say it is connected and moves ahead to fetch data . as even though net is connected but i m not receiving any packets of data . so how can i check if i m receiving and data from net then only i want to ahead . any help would be appreciated

```
public class Getlocation extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean isGpsworking = false, dialogshown = false;
String phone, lattitude, longitude;
LocationManager locationmanager;
Location location;
double userlat, userlng;
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
SharedPreferences pref;
boolean activitypaused = false;
ProgressDialog pdailog;
Geocoder geocoder;
StringBuilder temp_location;
TextView t1, t2;
Button b1;
CheckInternetConnection connected_to_internet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_getlocation);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    pdailog = new ProgressDialog(Getlocation.this);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_location_text_view);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_location_text_view_static);
    connected_to_internet = new CheckInternetConnection(getApplicationContext());
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //bar = getSupportActionBar()
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Location");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       sample.statusbarcolor(this);
    }
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_location_button);
    b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (pref.getString("lat", null) == null & pref.getString("lng", null) == null) {
        pdailog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        pdailog.setMessage("Please wait!Fecthing your Current location");
        pdailog.show();
        getloc();
        pdailog.dismiss();
    } else if (getIntent().getExtras().get("Coming_From").equals(0)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.sample.MAINACTIVITY");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else if (getIntent().getExtras().get("Coming_From").equals(1)) {
        t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (!(pref.getString("Location_Name", null)).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            t1.setText("" + pref.getString("Location_Name", "No Location Found"));
        }


    }
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pdailog.setTitle("please wait");
            pdailog.setMessage("Please wait!Fecthing your Current location");
            pdailog.show();
            getloc();
            pdailog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.getlocation, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem homeItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionHome);
    homeItem.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        case R.id.actionHome:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.sample.MAINACTIVITY");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void getloc() {
    if (connected_to_internet.Connected_To_Internet()) {
        locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationmanager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 *5, 1, this);
        } else if (!(dialogshown)) {
            showSettingsAlert();

        }
        Runnable run_object = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (locationmanager != null) {
                        try {
                            location = locationmanager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            if (location == null) {
                                getloc();
                            }
                        }
                        if (location != null) {
                            userlat = location.getLatitude();
                            userlng = location.getLongitude();
                            List<Address> address;
                            String locality = null;
                            try {
                                address = geocoder.getFromLocation(userlat, userlng, 1);
                                temp_location = new StringBuilder();


                                Address add = address.get(0);


                                temp_location.append(add.getSubLocality());
                                locality = add.getLocality();

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            if (!locality.equalsIgnoreCase(temp_location.toString())) {
                                pref.edit().putString("Location_Name", temp_location.toString() + ", " + locality).commit();
                                pref.edit().putString("City_name",locality).commit();
                            } else {
                                pref.edit().putString("Location_Name", temp_location.toString()).commit();
                                pref.edit().putString("City_name",locality).commit();
                            }
                            pref.edit().putString("lat", Double.toString(userlat)).commit();
                            pref.edit().putString("lng", Double.toString(userlng)).commit();
                            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("SplashScreen", false)) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent("com.sample.LOGIN");
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            } else {
                                Intent in = new Intent("com.sample.MAINACTIVITY");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your location is set to "+ temp_location.toString() + ", " + locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(in);
                            }

                        } else {
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Can Not Obtained! Closing Application. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Getlocation.this, SplashScreen.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
               /* if(!(dialogshown)) {
                    showSettingsAlert();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Turn-On Your GPS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }*/
                }
            }
        };
        new Handler().post(run_object);
    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Check Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogshown = true;
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Required");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Please go to settings and enable GPS.");
    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    dialogshown = false;
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().get("Coming_From").equals(1)) {
                          //do something

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Requires One-Time Location To Work Properly.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
```

}`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark

Comment: its not what i want ! i don't want monitor just in my application. i want it to programmatically very time internet is being connected @MorrisonChang

Comment: Did you mean you are connected to wifi but there is no internet or You want to check your server is down.

Comment: i m connected to wifi but  i m not receiving data . beacuse of very slow internet connection like 2G . beacuse of this it forces closes the application@WaleedSarwar