# Wireshark packet capture

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

If I use my phone's​ USB tethering feature to use internet on my PC, and play an Online Game on my phone, is there any way to capture those packets by Wireshark (or any other software you wanna suggest) ??
Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing mobile phone traffic on wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark)

Comment: Playing an online game on your phone doesn't interact with any active USB tethering. It goes straight to the gateway or mobile tower. So, no.

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which OS your PC is running, but the Wireshark [USB Capture Setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) wiki page is probably a good place to start as it provides useful information for both Linux and Windows platforms.

In a nutshell, on Linux you will need [usbmon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt) and on Windows you will need [USBPcap](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/), which you can also choose to install at the time you install Wireshark.  However, you should be aware of some past problems with USBPcap.  The problems ***should*** be resolved now but I'll leave you with some reading material:

- [Wireshark Bug 11766](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11766)
- [USBPcap Issue #3](https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/issues/3)
- [Microsoft Security Advisory 3033929](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityAdvisories/2015/3033929)

Alternatively, you can purchase a dedicated USB packet capture device, such as the [Beagle USB 12 Protocol Analyzer](https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/).

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with Total Phase in any way, nor have I used any of their products and so I have no idea of their products' capabilities.  Before purchasing any product, you should conduct your own research to be sure the product will meet your needs.