# Using Wireshark on a rooted android device with ssl decryption

Tags: android, ssl, wireshark, tcpdump, burp

The question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9555403/11358868) is quite outdated and vague, especially considering the changes with android 7.0+ and ssl. I've primarily used burp proxy to see the traffic going in and out of my device. My android is rooted and I've exported and installed burp suites root ca certificate according to [this tutorial](https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-burp-suite-with-android-nougat/). This allows me to see httpS and wsS traffic decrypted in clear text. The only issue with burp suite is http and websocket are the only protocols it natively supports. I have an android application that uses tcp socket and ssl. I want to use Wireshark to inspect that data. I've heard suggestions on how I might go about doing this. One of them is use something called tcpdump but I'm unfamilier and confused with that and other methods and I need to make sure I can decrypt the ssl.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the traffic from the rooted android device to a transparent TLS proxy, which decrypts and re-encrypts the TLS traffic while leaving the WebSocket data untouched. Both [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) (our tool) and [SSLsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit) can export the proxied traffic to a PCAP file in **decrypted** form. This allows you to inspect the decrypted WebSocket traffic in Wireshark without having to bother with key log files.