# Is there a way to profile latencies / communication overheads of AR Frameworks such as AR Core and AR Kit on mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am in the process of developing an AR Framework of my own. However, I need to benchmark the latencies / communication overhead of existing AR frameworks such as Google AR Core and Apple AR Kit on a mobile device. The communication overhead / latencies may include but not limited to following tasks:

- time taken for the AR application to communicate with cloud
- time taken for the AR application to start / re-start

Is there a **defined process** to find involved latencies / overheads similar to as we can use Batterystats to profile energy consumption of a mobile device? Are there any tools/ applications can be used to help find the latency / communication overhead benchmarks?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific requirement and I don't think you will find anything comparable to 'Batterystats' to give you this type of info out of the box.

However, for communications latency, there are many network sniffing tools you can use which include timing details. The most popular is probably Wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org

There are several ways to use Wireshark to analyse mobile phone traffic, within certain limitations - for example it can't read encrypted traffic. One of the easiest is to set up your laptop or PC as a mobile hotspot and run Wireshark there. This answer gives a good overview of other approaches also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570093/334402

Comment: Thanks Mick. Your answer regarding analysis of Phone Traffic using Wireshark is accurate. I just did that using Linux VM and creating a hotspot. That allowed me to monitor latencies, especially those involving the cloud.
As for the other question, I ran the application through Android Studio. Android Studio has a built in Profiler that allows for mobile device CPU, Memory and battery Monitoring. So to ascertain app start / re-start times, the profiler came in really handy. Also the profiler registers any touch on the app, which further helped in identification of application response times.

Comment: Interesting that the profiler helped you with this - that's good info to share.