# detection of real mobile device vs emulator, laptop requests for http web service

Tags: android

I have web service provider which will serve to only requests from only real mobile devices.  I tried using curl and it gets blocked.  can one help understand what all parameters are passed along by device implicitly that enables web service to detect the request is not from real device.  I have tried various user agent strings for browser both for pc and mobile devices but all get blocked stating user-agent not found.

Request works from real device.

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: I would propose that you use a tool such as Wireshark, from home access the service over a WiFi link from your mobile device, and capture the communications via wireshark (if possible). Then you may see what header information the provider is asking for, and possibly be able to emulate it.

Comment: @DaveM you are right.  I actually do not know how to capture mobile device traffic using wireshark.  I use it on pc.  I have though managed to get my request flow through the web service using curl with help from irc folks.  thanks for your help.  regards.

Comment: I just wondered how it was done myself, and found this thread on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904795/using-wireshark-on-the-pc-to-monitor-traffic-on-the-android-phone, I wonder if using an android dev environment on your actual pc (ie emulate your phone) would work also to capture the sent packets. When you find a good solution remember to post it to your question, as I'm sure this would be helpfull. Personally I want to do the same thing for my internet connections that streams the TV to the android device, but haven't got around to it yet.